# Dynamic workflow in odoo

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

How can we create a workflow dynamically in odoo?

for example:-

I want to select stages from master table where i have created 3 flows i.e. Semi flow, Full flow and simplified flow. If i select semi flow, only the stages that are in semi flow  should work and visible not all stages.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: for transition between stages `self.write({'state': 'state1'})`

Comment: and for hide a button in xml : `attrs="{'invisible': [('state','not in',['state1', 'state2'] )]}"`